# Having 2 Discord Apps installed

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, uninstall, duplicate, ubuntu-store

As you can read in the title, I accidentally installed 2 Discord apps; one is from the Ubuntu Software and the other is from the .deb file in the Discord website.
I came here to ask you if there's an easy way to uninstall the app from the .deb file to keep only the one from the Snap Store

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you installed the `.deb` and the Snap version, but only want to use the Snap version, just remove the package from the actual `apt` side of things to remove the installed `.deb`:

```
sudo apt remove discord
```

This doesn't affect the Snap version, and will remove the 'duplicate' Discord.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, It worked as intended.

Comment: @MartinPrado Understand that 1) Discord is pretty much spyware, and 2) The SNAP version will FLOOD /var/log/syslog if you don't give it permission to get out of its sandbox (very bad idea). IF you have to use Discord, I'd say use the .deb version, not the SNAP version.

Comment: @heynnema you have to back up any statements you make with legitimate evidence to support it - there's no evidence Discord is spyware (which makes the statement false)

Comment: @ThomasWard The comments aren't the correct place to add "legitimate evidence". Any app, like Discord, that monitors what OTHER apps that you're running, and then reacts to that data with a message to stay focused on Discord, is spyware in my book. What business is it for Discord to monitor your processes? Who knows where else that data gets sent? And the SNAP version wants out of its sandbox, or it'll flood syslog. Not good either.

Comment: @heynnema because this bumped up on the list.  You've done the same to me on other posts before of mine too, so...

Comment: @ThomasWard Any comments about my brief "legitimate evidence"?

Comment: @heynnema I mean, even if it's legitimate evidence, your opinion unrelated to the thing I'm asking for.